# Where I can find Axis WSDL2Java file?

Tags: java, axis

I downloaded Axis 1.4 ( http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/apache.org/ws/axis/1_4/ ) and I wanted to use WSDL2Java, but I didn't find such a file from package, but there are refrences to this file ( http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL ) in their site. Where I can get that file ?

Comment: Why are you using Axis 1.4? It's completely obsolete and unmaintained.

Comment: Our "partner" uses RPC/encoded SOAP messages, and CFX and Axis2 doesn't support that.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. My sympathies :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the doc](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL)

> You'll find the Axis WSDL-to-Java tool
>   in "org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java".
>   The basic invocation form looks like
>   this:
>
> % java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java
>   (WSDL-file-URL)

Comment: I'm quite sure there was such batch file in the distribution.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a simple bash script to invoke WSDL2Java that you can place in the "lib" directory and run:

```
#! /bin/bash

CP="."
for JAR in `ls *.jar`; do
        CP="$CP:$JAR"
done
#echo "classpath = $CP"
java -cp $CP org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java $@
```

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java`

Answer (score 5):

I thought I would provide an updated answer.  Currently, wsdl2java is located in the Apache CXF package.  If you extract it you will find handy scripts in the bin directory that simplify the execution process.

Download: http://cxf.apache.org/download.html
Directions for use: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I tried to use `wsdl2java` with axis 1.4. But couldn't find the `wsdl2java` file. What I did was, I have taken `wsdl2java` from `axis2` and modified according to axis 1.4 jar files and etc. I run it for axis 1.4. I could manage to get java class files with some warning. I dont bother about warning.

Anyway, I got all java class files from wsdl with axis 1.4. However, I feel that it would be better choice if you migrate it from axis 1.4 to axis2.

Comment: Use this to generate wsdl : java -classpath activation.jar;mailapi.jar;axis.jar;jaxrpc.jar;saaj.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;commons-discovery-0.2.jar;wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;log4j-1.2.8.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -s your_wsdl_name.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Download cxf from https://cxf.apache.org/download.html (Binary distribution)

Here is example for version 3.4.3.

Just unpack it to the desired folder and You can find it in
**apache-cxf-3.4.3\bin**